# AppleScript -- Can't access menu item due to long dash

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

I am trying to access a menu item in Safari using apple scrip within a .sh file but I keep getting errors due to I don't know how to handle the long dashes.

The item is within the Developer/User Agent menu. My OS is in Swedish but it should not matter.

So this is what I am currently trying to do:

```
click menu item "Safari—iOS 10—iPhone" of menu of menu item "Användaragent" of menu "Utvecklare" of menu bar 1
```

It works fine when accessing something else that does not include the long dash "—". I Am guessing I don't get a long dash when doing Shift+alt+- in the .sh file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to display all titles of the menu items.

```
activate application "Safari"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set menuTitles to title of menu items of menu of menu item "Användaragent" of menu "Utvecklare" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
tell application "Safari" to display dialog menuTitles as text
set text item delimiters to TID
```

Then copy & paste the text you need.